# How to click combobox search dropdown in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, combobox, dropdown

I want to select an item from the combobox search dropdown.

Html Code of the website is:

```
 <div class="form-group">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6 margin-bottom">
 <select id="CustomerCard_state" class="form-control m-b drop_state"                          tabindex="-1" name="CustomerCard.state" data-val-required="Please enter State"        data-val="true" style="display: none;">
 <option value="">Please select state</option>
 <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
 <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
 <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
 <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
 <option value="CA">California</option>
 <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
 <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
 <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
 <option value="FL">Florida</option>
 <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
 <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
 <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
 <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
 <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
 <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
 <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
 <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
 <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
 <option value="ME">Maine</option>
 <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
 <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
 <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
 <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
 <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
 <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
 <option value="MT">Montana</option>
 <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
 <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
 <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
 <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
 <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
 <option value="NY">New York</option>
 <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
 <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
 <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
 <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
 <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
 <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
 <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
 <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
 <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
 <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
 <option value="TX">Texas</option>
 <option value="UT">Utah</option>
 <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
 <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
 <option value="WA">Washington</option>
 <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
 <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
 <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
 </select>
 <div id="CustomerCard_state_chosen" class="chosen-container chosen-        container-single chosen-with-drop chosen-container-active" style="width: 100%;"   title="">
 <a class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1">
 <span>Please select state</span>
 <div>
 <b/>
 </div>
 </a>
 <div class="chosen-drop">
 <div class="chosen-search">
 <input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="16"/>
 </div>
 <ul class="chosen-results">
 <li class="active-result result-selected" style="" data-option-array-       index="0">Please select state</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">Alaska</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="2">Alabama</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="3">Arizona</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array- index="4">Arkansas</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="5">California</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-     index="6">Colorado</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-     index="7">Connecticut</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="8">Delaware</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="9">Florida</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-     index="10">Georgia</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="11">Hawaii</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="12">Idaho</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="13">Illinois</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="14">Indiana</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="15">Iowa</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="16">Kansas</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="17">Kentucky</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="18">Louisiana</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="19">Maine</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="20">Maryland</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="21">Massachusetts</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="22">Michigan</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="23">Minnesota</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="24">Mississippi</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="25">Missouri</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="26">Montana</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="27">Nebraska</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="28">Nevada</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="29">New Hampshire</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="30">New Jersey</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="31">New Mexico</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="32">New York</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="33">North Carolina</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="34">North Dakota</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="35">Ohio</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="36">Oklahoma</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="37">Oregon</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="38">Pennsylvania</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="39">Rhode Island</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="40">South Carolina</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="41">South Dakota</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="42">Tennessee</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="43">Texas</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="44">Utah</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="45">Vermont</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="46">Virginia</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="47">Washington</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="48">West Virginia</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="49">Wisconsin</li>
 <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="50">Wyoming</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 <span class="text-danger drop_state-error " style="display:none;"/>
 </div>
```

My selenium code is:

```
    WebElement select = BrowserSetup.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'chosen-container')]"));
    select.click();

    List<WebElement> dropDowns = BrowserSetup.driver.findElements(By.className("chosen-results"));

    WebElement dropDownOne = dropDowns.get(0); // perform further action
    dropDownOne.click();
```

It is throwing an exception : 
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible at line :
    WebElement dropDownOne = dropDowns.get(0); dropDownOne.click();

I have also tired to add explicit wait with following code

```
    WebElement select =     BrowserSetup.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'chosen-  container')]"));
    select.click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(BrowserSetup.driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.className("chosen-results")));

    List<WebElement> dropDowns = BrowserSetup.driver.findElements(By.className("chosen-results"));

    WebElement dropDownOne = dropDowns.get(0); // perform further action
    dropDownOne.click();
```

What can I do to resolve this issue? It is working when i debug my code, but it throws exception when i run my program.

Comment: I'm not sure as to the inner workings of Selenium, but if the element's not visible.. Have you tried clicking the combobox first and then trying to click the element of your choosing?

Comment: Can you tell the version of the driver and browser and which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: @TomNijs yes as you can see in my selenium code i have tried clicking on the container (combobox)

Comment: @FlorentB.Selenium driver version is 2.53, chrome52.0 is the browser and exception is at line: WebElement dropDownOne = dropDowns.get(0); dropDownOne.click();

Comment: Did you tried using `Select` class??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur yea i tried Select class also, but it did not work because this dropdown is having a searchbox also .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(BrowserSetup.driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.className("chosen-results")));
```

to:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(BrowserSetup.driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("chosen-results")));
```

May it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it using actions.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(BrowserSetup.driver);

WebElement select = BrowserSetup.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'chosen-container')]"));
List<WebElement> dropDowns = BrowserSetup.driver.findElements(By.className("chosen-results"));

actions.moveToElement(select).click().moveToElement(dropDowns.get(0)).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @nickQ. but It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has [Select](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) class to handle dropdowns

```
WebElement dropdown = BrowserSetup.driver.findElement(By.id("CustomerCard_state"));
Select select = new Select(dropdown);

// to choose Alaska
select.selectByValue("AK");
// or
select.selectByVisibleText("Alaska");
```

Please note it will work only on `<select>` tags.

Comment: @Harry Yes it does `<select id="CustomerCard_state" class="form-control m-b drop_state"`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting ul element, that's the reason of the error. You should get li elements under ul. Try:

```
BrowserSetup.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='chos‌​en-results']/li"));
```